# Pagination in a SQL Server stored procedure with duplicated data

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, pagination

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that gets contact persons based on multiple filters (e.g. `DateOfBirth`, `DisplayName`, ...) from multiple tables. I need to alter the stored procedure to include pagination and total count, since the pagination was done in the backend. `PartyId` is the unique key. The caveat is that a person can have multiple emails and phones, and let's say we search for `DisplayName = "Sarah"`, the query will return the following :

```
TotalCount  PartyId     DisplayName EmailAddress      PhoneNumber   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
3           1           Sarah       sarah@gmail.com   1
3           1           Sarah       sarah2@gmail.com  1
3           1           Sarah       sarah@gmail.com   2
```

This is roughly what the stored procedure does, the assigned values for `CurrentPage` and `PageSize` and the `ORDER BY OFFSET` on the bottom I included to test the pagination :

```
DECLARE @CurrentPage int = 1
DECLARE @PageSize int = 1000

SELECT 
    COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount,
    p.Id AS PartyId,
    e.EmailAddress,
    pn.PhoneNumber
    etc.....                            
FROM 
    [dbo].[Party] AS p WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Email] AS e WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.[Id] = e.[PartyID]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[PhoneNumber] AS pn WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.[Id] = pn.[PartyID]    
    etc.....
WHERE 
    p.PartyType = 1 /*Individual*/ 
GROUP BY 
    p.Id, e.EmailAddress, pn.PhoneNumber etc...  
ORDER BY 
    p.Id 
    OFFSET (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

This is what we do in the backend to group by `PartyId` and assign the corresponding emails and phones.

```
var responseModel = unitOfWork.PartyRepository.SearchContacts(model);

if (responseModel != null && responseModel.Count == 0)
{
    return null;
}

// get multiple phones/emails for a party
var emailAddresses = responseModel.GroupBy(p => new { p.PartyId, p.EmailAddress })
                            .Select(x => new {
                                    x.Key.PartyId,
                                    x.Key.EmailAddress
                            });

var phoneNumbers = responseModel.GroupBy(p => new { p.PartyId, p.PhoneNumber, p.PhoneNumberCreateDate })
                            .Select(x => new {
                                    x.Key.PartyId,
                                    x.Key.PhoneNumber,
                                    x.Key.PhoneNumberCreateDate
                            }).OrderByDescending(p => p.PhoneNumberCreateDate);

// group by in order to avoid multiple records with different email/phones
responseModel = responseModel.GroupBy(x => x.PartyId)
                   .Select(grp => grp.First())
                   .ToList();

var list = Mapper.Map<List<SearchContactResponseModelData>>(responseModel);

// add all phones/emails to respective party
list = list.Select(x =>
                    {
                        x.EmailAddresses = new List<string>();
                        x.EmailAddresses.AddRange(emailAddresses.Where(y => y.PartyId == x.PartyId).Select(y => y.EmailAddress));

                        x.PhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
                        x.PhoneNumbers.AddRange(phoneNumbers.Where(y => y.PartyId == x.PartyId).Select(y => y.PhoneNumber));
                        return x;
                    }).ToList();

var sorted = SortAndPagination(model, model.SortBy, list);

SearchContactResponseModel result = new SearchContactResponseModel()
            {
                Data = sorted,
                TotalCount = list.Count
            };

return result;
```

And the response will be :

```
{
  "TotalCount": 1,
  "Data": [
    {
      "PartyId": 1,
      "DisplayName": "SARAH",
      "EmailAddresses": [
        "sarah@gmail.com",
        "sarah2@gmail.com"
      ],
      "PhoneNumbers": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The TotalCount returned from the stored procedure obviously is not the real one, and after the backend code (where we assign the emails/phones and group by id) we get the real totalCount which is 1 instead of 3.

If we have 3 persons with the name Sarah, because of multiple phones/emails the totalCount in the stored procedure will be lets say 9 and the real count will be 3 and if I execute the stored procedure to get persons from 1 to 2, the pagination wont work because of the 9 records.

How can I implement pagination in the above scenario ?

Comment: count() over with group by does not make sense to me

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using a CTE to isolate the query against the Party table. This would allow you to pull the right number of rows (and the proper total row count) without having to worry about the expansion from the emails and phone numbers.

It would look something like this (rearranging your query above):

```
DECLARE @CurrentPage int = 1;
DECLARE @PageSize int = 1000;

WITH PartyList AS (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount,
        p.Id AS PartyId         
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Party] AS p WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE 
        p.PartyType = 1 /*Individual*/ 
    GROUP BY -- You might not need this now depending on your data
        p.Id
    ORDER BY 
        p.Id 
        OFFSET (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT
    pl.TotalCount,
    pl.PartyId,
    e.EmailAddress,
    pn.PhoneNumber   
FROM PartyList AS pl
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[Email] AS e WITH(NOLOCK) ON pl.[PartyId] = e.[PartyID]
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[PhoneNumber] AS pn WITH(NOLOCK) ON pl.[PartyId] = pn.[PartyID];
```

Please be aware that the CTE will require the prior statement to end in a semicolon.

Comment: @OldGodOfAsgard My guess would be that they would optimize similarly, but it's hard to tell just by looking at the query. If you're concerned about the performance characteristics, I would compare execution plans between the two.

Comment: Thank you, I tried, there is no significant change in the speed. One more question, how can I ORDER BY lets say Emails in the CTE, because if pagination works, lets say get me 10 records with EmailAddress desc, i need to order by in the CTE by email so I can get the correct PartyIds, but it says "Column "Email.EmailAddress" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." which in turn i need to add it to the group by clause, but if I add it, it will not get me the correct partyIds. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @OldGodOfAsgard Sorry, I'm not sure there's enough information here to help out with that. Since each party can have multiple email addresses, I'm having trouble picturing how the sorting would be applied and displayed to the user. For example, if a party had two emails, one starting with "a" and the other starting with "z", how would that sort? My thoughts are that this fundamentally changes both the display and the query. Maybe that would be a completely different view (by email address).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!